# Stop Second Div wrappng around floated Div

Tags: html, css

I am having a small issue with positioning of a div within my project.

```
+------------------------+
|+-------+ ~~~~     TITLE| <--how can I stop the text wrapping up the 
||       | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ |\                      left hand side here?
||       | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | \
||       | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ |  \
||       | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ |   \
|+-------+            ^  |   Title Div (class="widgetHeader" in example)
+---------------------|--+
   ^                  |
   |                   \
 Thermometer div        \
 (all good)              \
                       "widgetContent" in example fiddle
```

However, I wish to force the div's title to stop the content from wrapping around it.

Something like:

```
+------------------------+
|+-------+          TITLE|  
||       | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ |
||       | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | 
||       | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ |  
||       | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ |   
|+-------+ ~~~~~         |   
+------------------------+
```

I what I wish to force on each widget.

[This is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/f7zLnjpk/4/)

The two main classes are:

```
.widgetHeader {
    padding-top:5%;
    float:right;
    margin-right:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.widgetContent {
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top:20%;
}
```

Which is at the end of the CSS in the example.

I know I can solve this easily enough using the `<br />` tags within the HTML, but I'm sure it *should* be easily possible to implement this here.

I think the main problem here is that the `Title` is right aligned and the content is left aligned.

Any CSS solution (since it will be designed for varying sized screens, I prefer to use %'s instead of px's)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixing the code**

Don't `float` it, instead you can right align it with `text-align`, like so:

```
.widgetHeader {
    padding-top:5%;
    margin-right:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:right;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7zLnjpk/5/)

---

**An alternate approach**

If I was doing this myself from scratch I would likely do something like this:

```css
.main {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    background-color:#EEE;
    padding:5px;
}
.image {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
.content {
    display:block;
    margin-left:130px;
    color:#444;
}
.title {
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">Title Here</div>
        <p>The rest of the content goes here and will look beautiful and majestic.</p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3g9v7v4j/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - however, how would you stop the word 'long' from wrapping under the 'thermometer'?

Comment: @jbutler483: See my edit for an improved (in my opinion) solution

Comment: i'ts quite a clean solution you have there. Not quite sure what the 'Clear:both' is doing, but it has quite a few nice aspects that I could (probably should) use. Cheers!

Comment: @jbutler483: try removing the `clear:both` and you will see what it is for ;)

Answer (score 1):

For class "`.widgetHeader`" remove property "`float: right`" and add "`text-align: right;`". This will solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using float use `text-align: right` and `display: block`(to prevent the title to wrap under the thermometer div)

```
.widgetHeader {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top:5%;
    margin-right:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7zLnjpk/6/)

OR

You can still use float and put a max-width of your title div.

```
 .widgetHeader {
    max-width: 150px;
    float: right;
    padding-top:5%;
    margin-right:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7zLnjpk/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You only have to change one thing (2 if u want to make it a little better looking):

```
    .widgetHeader {
    text-align:right; <--- add this
    margin-right:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Delete the padding-top.
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7zLnjpk/9/)